# Issue in returning interface as return type in Java

Tags: java, android, types, interface, return

I have the following code:

---

**`Filename: A.java`**

```
package test1

public interface A {
   int get();
   int set();
}
```

---

**`Filename: B.java`**

```
package test1
public class B implements A {

    int get() {
       ...
    }

    int set() {
     ....
    }
}
```

---

**`Filename: C.java`**

```
package test2

import test1.A;
import test1.B;

publc class C {

        public A getNum() {
             B test = null;

             return(test);
        }
}
```

---

When I compiled the above code in Eclipse--> Sample Java Project, It is working fine. But when I compiled the same code in Android, It is throwing the following error:: Method C.getNum returns unavailable type A;

Please let me know, where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Kranti

Comment: Same package declared? And does `C.java` have a class definition?

Comment: You will need to copy and paste your exact code. Particularly useful when talking about compiler error messages (copy and paste those too).

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: Yeah, C.Java has the class definition. I have updated the code. please check it again and let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: Compiler throws Method C.getNum returns unavailable type A; No other errors/warnings.

Comment: Include the package name in the import `import Test1.A;`

Comment: @Kranti It should be "package src.Test1;" i.e. use "." instead of "/". Also import statement should be "import src.Test1.A;"

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, @Tigris: Yes, I have added test1.A, test1.B. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

`Inteface` and `Implements` are not java keywords. You should use `interface` and `implements` instead. Java is case sensitive. Type `A` is unavailable on the class path due to other compilation errors.

the following code should work:

```
public class Test {
    interface  A {
        int get();
        int set();
    }

    class B implements A {

        @Override
        public int get() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int set() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    class C {
        public A getNum(){
            A a = new B();
            return a; 
        }
    }
}
```

I've produced that code based on your example. But you know I cannot imagine what this code is useful for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A.java, B.java are in test directory and C.java is in the root directory the above code has many issues

1. Interface and Implements should be small caps i.e "interface" and "implements"
2. interface methods are public even if not declared. So when implementing it in B both get and set should be public
3. A.java and B.java should have package test; as the first line
4. You need to import test.A; import test.B;
5. There is no class declaration for C
6. B test = 0; is wrong. It should be either B test = null; or B test = new B(); depending on what you plan to use. 0 is an integer and can't be cast to B
7. return B is not valid as B is a class name. You probably intended return test;

Here's a modified code

A.java

```
package test;
public interface A {
    int get();
    int set();
}
```

B.java

```
package test;
public class B implements A {

    public int get() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int set() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

C.java

```
import test.A;
import test.B;

public class C {
    public A getNum() {
        B test = new B();

        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alex and @Tigris: Thank you very much for the information. Sorry that I couldnt write the syntax properly in the question. As you suggested, the actual code is like that only. And C.Java is in another directory. Thats the reason, I am importing the other classes. In C.Java ->  getNum() --> I am returning (test). But the compiler is throwing an error saying: getNum() returns unavailable type A.

Comment: @Kranti You must've forgotten to put package declaration in A/B.java. I've updated to code as if A and B.java reside in test package

Comment: Hmm.. No.. With the changes as import src/Test1.A ; import src/Test1.B; also I am getting the same compilation error.

Comment: @Kranti import and package statements use "." and not "/" as separator. If you want the root package name to be "src" then package declaration will be "package src.Test1" and "package src.Test2" and import statement will be "import src.Test1.A;" and "import src.Test1.B;"

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is just to mention the package declaration i.e. package test1 in the interface A file.

Comment: Sorry, I dnt get you.. Do you mean to say, there should not be any package declaration in A.Java?